# How to remove ampersand, pound & number from a http response string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, replace, encoding

I currently have an API that returns the following string inside parentheses

```
(Multivitamin Gummies - Berry, Peach & Orange - 150ct - Up&Up&#8482;)
```

I want it to be instead formatted to the user like so

```
(Multivitamin Gummies - Berry, Peach & Orange - 150ct - Up&Up)
```

Is there a way to dynamically do this fix this in javascript?

Here is another example:

```
(Aloe Hand Sanitizer Gel - 8 fl oz - Up&#38;Up&#8482;)
```

should return

```
(Aloe Hand Sanitizer Gel - 8 fl oz - Up&Up)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
var str = 'Aloe Hand Sanitizer Gel - 8 fl oz - Up&Up™';

console.log(str.match(/[^™]+/)[0]);
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove &#38 and &#8482 dynamically as they are being shown in place of tm superscript in the UI? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the characters you want to replace in the or `|` like below in the regex and replace using `.replace()`

```
/™|&#38|&#8482/g
```

```js
var str = 'Aloe Hand Sanitizer Gel - &#8482 8 fl oz - Up&Up™';
console.log(str.replace(/™|&#38|&#8482/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to replace all Unicode with empty string.

You can use regex `str.replace(/(&#\d+;)/g,"")` to remove these characters

```js
var str = '(Multivitamin Gummies - Berry, Peach & Orange - 150ct - Up&Up&#8482;)';
console.log(str.replace(/(&#\d+;)/g,""));

str = '(Aloe Hand Sanitizer Gel - 8 fl oz - Up&#38;Up&#8482;) ';
console.log(str.replace(/(&#\d+;)/g,""));
```